# What can make a sidekiq worker produce eroneous or even impossible method responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

We have a Worker which had a bug that caused eroneous responses to a method being called. The issue has since been fixed, however when we restart the background workers we seem to still experience the issue.

We know the issue is resolved because for the meantime we have moved the logic to a rake task and it is now working fine. We suspect the issue relates to failed or unperformed jobs in the sidekiq queue.

We tried to overcome this by clearing the redis DB with the below approach:

```
Sidekiq.redis { |r| puts r.flushall }
```

Has anyone experienced a similar issue when using Sidekiq/Redis and how did you over come it?

Comment: Are you sure that your background workers were actually updated successfully? Are you sure that you restarted all your Sidekiq instances, and that there isn't some rogue worker running the old codebase that picks up the job first? Is the issue reproducible in development, or only in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think flushall might just retry immediately all the still failed, but still queued, jobs

In most cases, if you fix a bug in the worker without changing the *signature*, you may be able to just let them retry (assuming the job itself is idempotent which is kinda recommended for this reason and others).

If however, the bug was in what you were *passing into* the async job call, then you'll have to remove all those entries because they will continue to fail every time they are retried which, by default, can go on for weeks.

I think what you want to do is clear them all... you can do it for that particular queue. You may have to be careful to not remove jobs that are newly queued if that's a problem by perhaps examining the job entries. If you just want to nuke them all:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new('your_queue')
queue.clear
```

Comment: ·Sometimes should ```require 'sidekiq/api'``` before use ```Sidekiq::Queue```